# Why can't objgraph capture the growth of np.array()?

Tags: python, numpy, memory-leaks, memory-leak-detector, objgraph

See the code:

```
import objgraph
import numpy as np
objgraph.show_growth()
j = 20
y = []
for i in range(5):
    for l in range(j):
        y.append(np.array([np.random.randint(500),np.random.randint(500)]))
    print 'i:',i
    objgraph.show_growth()
    print '___'
    #objgraph.show_most_common_types(limit=100)
    j += 1
```

the result is:

```
i: 1
wrapper_descriptor 1596 +3
weakref 625 +1
dict 870 +1
method_descriptor 824 +1
i: 2
i: 3
i: 4
```

For the 2,3 and 4 epoch, it shows nothing growing. But it should show that the number of numpy.array grows

Comment: My guess is that you need to study the `objgraph` documentation to learn what it can and cannot detect.  And scan other `objgraph` SO questions.  There aren't many with a `numpy` application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with `objgraph` specifically, but I think the same issue applies to other Python heap analysis tools such as [`heapy`](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/#Heapy).

Numpy arrays are implemented in C, and do their own [reference counting](https://docs.python.org/2.7/extending/extending.html#reference-counts) by internally calling `Py_INCREF` and `Py_DECREF`. As such, they are not tracked by the Python [garbage collector](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html). Tools like `heapy` and (presumably) `objgraph` use the Python garbage collector to track references to objects, so as a result numpy arrays are invisible to them.