# memory leak (cython + numpy)

Tags: numpy, memory-leaks, cython

I'm struggling to find where the leak is in this code

***kullback.pyx***

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

import scipy.stats as st
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


cdef vector[double] minmax(double i, dict a):
    cdef double minmax 
    cdef vector[double] out

    try:
        minmax= min(list(filter(lambda x: x > i, a.keys())))
    except ValueError:
        minmax = min(a.keys())

    cdef double maxmin

    try:
        maxmin = max(list(filter(lambda x: x < i, a.keys())))
    except ValueError:
        maxmin = max(a.keys())

    out.push_back(minmax)
    out.push_back(maxmin)

    return out

def KullbackLeibler(args):

    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim = 1] psample = args[0]
    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim = 1] qsample = args[1]
    cdef int n = args[2]

    a = plt.hist(psample, bins = n)

    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim = 1] ax = a[1]

    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim = 1] ay = a[0]

    b = plt.hist(qsample, bins = ax)

    adict = dict(zip(ax, ay))    
    ax = ax[:-1]

    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim = 1] bx = b[1]
    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim = 1] by = b[0]
    bdict = dict(zip(bx, by))

    bx = bx[:-1]

    cdef vector[double] kl

    cdef int N = np.sum(ay)

    cdef int i
    cdef double p_minmax, p_maxmin, q_minmax, q_maxmin
    cdef double KL

    for i in range(len(psample)):

        ptmp = minmax(psample[i], adict)

        p_minmax = ptmp[0]
        p_maxmin = ptmp[1]

        qtmp = minmax(psample[i], bdict)
        q_minmax = qtmp[0]
        q_maxmin = qtmp[1]

        pdensity = adict[p_maxmin]/ N
        qdensity = np.max([bdict[q_maxmin]/ N, 10e-20])

        KL = pdensity * np.log(pdensity/qdensity)

        kl.push_back(KL)

    cdef double res = np.sum(kl)

    del args, psample, qsample, ax, ay, bx, by, adict, bdict

    return res
```

here the main from which I launch

**main.py**

```
import kullback as klcy #@unresolvedimport

import datetime
import numpy as np

import pathos.pools as pp
import objgraph

np.random.seed(10)

ncore = 4
pool = pp.ProcessPool(ncore)

KL = []

for i in range(2500):

    time1 = datetime.datetime.now()

    n = 500                                           
    x = [np.random.normal(size = n, scale = 1) for j in range(ncore)]
    y = [np.random.normal(size = n, scale = 1) for j in range(ncore)]

    data = np.array(list(zip(x,y,[n/10]*ncore)))

    kl = pool.map(klcy.KullbackLeibler, data)

    time2 = datetime.datetime.now()

    print(i, time2 - time1, sep = "      ")

    print(objgraph.show_growth())
    KL.append(kl)
```

The function `KullbackLeibler` takes as input two arrays and an integer

What I've already tried:

1. using objgraph to identify growing objects, unfortunately it seems it doesn't work with C-defined arrays (it identifies only the list in which I'm appending the result as growing)
   [Why can't objgraph capture the growth of np.array()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563978/why-cant-objgraph-capture-the-growth-of-np-array)
2. deleting all the arrays at the end of the pyx function
3. tried placing a `gc.collect()` call both in the pyx file and in the main file, but nothing has changed

Memory consumption grows linearly with the number of iterations, along with the time required for each iteration (from 0.6s to over 4s). It's my first attempt with cython, any suggestion would be useful.

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] (minimal being very important) - I would start with deleting `plt.hist`-stuff and reduce the example further and further. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388123/5769463

Comment: I'd be __very__ suspicious of `plt`. If you don't close the plot then it can remain open holding memory forever.

Comment: @DavidW you nailed it. After @ead comment I was deleting that stuff...re-running there was no leak. After putting a ```plt.close()```  in the end, the leak was gone. I was looking in the wrong place focusing on arrays. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with arrays. I wasn't closing matplotlib plots

`a = plt.hist(psample, bins = n)`

`b = plt.hist(qsample, bins = ax)`

Even if I wasn't displaying them they were drawn nonetheless, consuming memory which was never freed afterwards. Thanks to @DavidW in the comments for making me notice.