# How do I free a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I want to remove the whole numpy array. For instance, if I make array **`A`** like

```
A = np.zeros((2,3))
```

I want to remove the whole array `A` and want to reuse the name 'A' in other purpose.

Are there any codes (functions) to delete the array?

Comment: Python is a memory-managed language, and objects are automatically reclaimed once their reference count reaches zero.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ... except numpy is not really python and doesn't necessarily work that way

Comment: @Jivan yes, it is. And yes, it does.

Comment: well, try `del my_numpy_array_taking_50gb_in_memory` and see what happens in htop then — memory is still allocated

Comment: @Jivan read the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455048/releasing-memory-in-python

Comment: @Jivan and also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310668/is-freeing-handled-differently-for-small-large-numpy-arrays

Answer (score 2):

> *I want to remove the whole array A*

### Easy :

```
del A
```

> *want to reuse the name 'A' in other purpose.*

### Similarly easy :

```
A = whateverElse  # associate A with whateverElse, so simple :o)
```

Comment: this doesn't free the memory. somehow the array continues to be attached to the memory (even though the variable is not accessible anymore)

Comment: @Jivan - sure, such cases are possible. May test **`A.flags`** before having done the **`del A`** to see more details. Numpy uses smart structures for vector/matrix/tensor data storage & manipulation. Some even do not "own" its own data & are just a ***lightweight-"reader"***-helper into another numpy-object's data, so deleting such non-"owner" will for obvious reasons delete just the ***lightqweight-"reader"-helper***, not the **fat**-*(_foreign by ownership_)*-**data** itself.

Comment: any idea how to free memory from the fat data in these cases, then?

Comment: @Jivan *there is no way to explicitly free memory in Python*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga does it mean that if we create a 50gb array in memory and `del` doesn't free it, then there's no other way to free this memory than killing the process?

Comment: @Jivan Yes, essentially. Now, you must understand, that memory may actually be free for the process to use on other python objects... It is a "high water mark". So the object may be freed but your process is still utilizing the memory, from the POV of the operating system. It's also important to understand that `del` doesn't free anything, it deletes a *variable*, which may or may not cause a reference count to reach 0 (which in CPython causes an object to be reclaimed immediately)

Comment: > "_memory may actually be free for the process to use on other python objects_"
— i'd rather take your word, but unfortunately this is not what i'm observing — once i allocate a 50gb array, these 50gb are lost forever while the process is running (this is also very annoying, so if you had a solution for this i'd be happy to listen)

Comment: FYI - the O/P asked about using the variable name for other purpose, so the association is the subject, not the low-level memory-management ( Python Interpreter, since ever, does not operate any user-facing interface on how to (de)allocate memory for it's object-instances, so remarks about C-language alike free()-ing memory are off-topic here, inside a Python Interpreter context. There is a user-code accessible tool to stimulate or inhibit garbage collection, yet again, it does not meet the O/P indicated problem, the less the context of the said will to re-use the variable name A for other var

Answer (score 0):

Just assign A to something else.  As @juanpa.arrivillaga said, Python will take care of the now "un-referenced" array and do any garbage collection itself.
e.g. `A = "new string"`